# What algorithm should be used when matching hobby?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, matching, string-matching

I have tens of thousands of user data in dating app. Each user has 5 non-overlapping hobbies.
need to list them by connecting the couples with the most matching hobbies.

example

user1: {
  name: sam
  hobbies: ["A", "B", "C", "E", "H"]
}

user2: {
  name: sam
  hobbies: ["E", "B", "C", "Z", "H"]
}

user3: {
  name: sam
  hobbies: ["A", "B", "C", "E", "J"]
}

result :
user1 - user3

if user1, user2, user3 hobby is same result is
user1 - user2,
user1 - user3,
user2 - user3

I would like to know some algorithms or hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observation if total distinct hobbies fits into 64-bit integer range, then we can store each user data as an integer whose binary representation represents a hobbies. For example:

```
0th bit -> hobby A
1st bit -> hobby B
2nd bit -> hobby C
and so on ...
```

If user-1 has hobby  ["A", "B", "C", "E", "H"] then its binary representation will be:

```
           H  E CBA
           10010111
Integer =  151
```

If user-2 has hobby  ["A", "B", "C", "E", "J"]  then its binary representation will be:

```
           J    E CBA
           1000010111
Integer =  535
```

Then, total matching hobbies in between user-1 and user-2 can be obtained simply finding total one bits in an integer obtained by performing bitwise AND operation of these two integers.

```
Bitwise AND of (151 & 535) = 23 (10111) which has 4 ones in binary representation.

      151 = 0010010111
      535 = 1000010111
----------------------
and_a_b   = 0000010111

Basically, Bitwise AND will keep 1 bit only if both bit position are 1s.
Here, total hobbies match is = 4 which is total 1 bits in and_a_b.
```

In c++, We can obtain this value simply applying `__builtin_popcount(and_a_b)`.
We can get this in constant time in modern on modern hardware, since it provides POPCNT processor instruction for counting number of 1s bits ([Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT)).

In order to find most matching score, we can simply iterate over every pairs of user and calculate matching hobbies by simply finding total 1s bit in bitwise AND of two numbers and maximize that score. Now, in order to find list of most matching pairs, we can perform same thing and compare with most matching score and put them in our list.

Comment: Thank you buddy. There are 26 types of hobbies. I will try this way.
but how to find best matching couple list? There are too many data.

Answer (score 0):

1. **create table `hobby` of hobbies**

   so create a list of all **distinct** hobbies you got in your data.
2. **convert your hobby strings in your data to numbers**

   simply take each hobby string and look for it in your new `hobby` table. When found the `index` you found it on is the number you looking for. If not found add new entry to `hobby` and use its `index`.

   steps #1 and #2 can be done together. They might be speeded up by hashing and index sorting by the hash.
3. **brute force check of hobbies**

   now do 2 nested for loops to check each entriy agains each other entry in your data like:

   ```cpp
   for (i=0;i<entries-1;i++)
    for (j=i+1;j<entries;j++)
     ...
   ```

   and inside count the number of identical numbers (hobbies). So again 2 for loops but counting to `5` instead of up to `entries`.